# this.$el.querySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

The returndata get from the database and the returndata insert to the input and submit them as a form. The data is an object that pass the value to the database.

When I triggered this form here come the Error.
[Error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gviVy.png)

```html
<input id="merchantCode" type="text" name="merchantCode"   @ionInput="merchantPaymentInfo.merchantCode = $event.target.value;" v-model="merchantPaymentInfo.merchantCode" />
<input id="merchantKey" type="text" name="merchantKey"  @ionInput="merchantPaymentInfo.merchantKey = $event.target.value;" @ionChange="merchantPaymentInfo.merchantKey = $event.target.value;" v-model="merchantPaymentInfo.merchantKey" />
<input id="orderRef" type="text" name="orderRef"  @ionInput="merchantPaymentInfo.orderRef = $event.target.value;" @ionChange="merchantPaymentInfo.orderRef = $event.target.value;" v-model="merchantPaymentInfo.orderRef" />
<input id="amount" type="text" name="amount"  @ionInput="merchantPaymentInfo.amount = $event.target.value;" @ionChange="merchantPaymentInfo.amount = $event.target.value;" v-model="merchantPaymentInfo.amount" />
<input id="refNo" type="text" name="refNo"  @ionInput="merchantPaymentInfo.refNo = $event.target.value;" @ionChange="merchantPaymentInfo.refNo = $event.target.value;" v-model="merchantPaymentInfo.refNo" />
<input id="currCode" type="text" name="currCode"   @ionInput="merchantPaymentInfo.currCode = $event.target.value;" @ionChange="merchantPaymentInfo.currCode = $event.target.value;" v-model="merchantPaymentInfo.currCode" />
<input id="installmentPeriod" type="text" name="installmentPeriod"  @ionInput="merchantPaymentInfo.installmentPeriod = $event.target.value;" @ionChange="merchantPaymentInfo.installmentPeriod = $event.target.value;" v-model="merchantPaymentInfo.installmentPeriod" />
```

```typescript
//Typescript vuejs
async cartMergeRepurchase(data:object){
      const res =  await CartService.repurchase(data).then(function (response) {
                  return response;
              }) 
              //console.log(res);
              let returnData = null;

              if(res.data.success)
              {
                  returnData = res.data.returnData;

                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.merchantUrl = returnData.merchantUrl;
                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.merchantCode = returnData.merchantCode;
                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.merchantKey = returnData.merchantKey;
                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.orderRef = returnData.orderRef;
                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.amount = returnData.amount;
                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.refNo = returnData.refNo;
                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.currCode = returnData.currCode;
                  this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.installmentPeriod = returnData.installmentPeriod;
                  
                  this.$el.querySelector("#merchantCode").value = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.merchantCode;
                  this.$el.querySelector("#merchantKey").value = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.merchantKey;
                  this.$el.querySelector("#orderRef").value = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.orderRef;
                  this.$el.querySelector("#amount").value = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.amount;
                  this.$el.querySelector("#refNo").value = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.refNo;
                  this.$el.querySelector("#currCode").value = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.currCode;
                  this.$el.querySelector("#installmentPeriod").value = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.installmentPeriod;
                  this.$el.querySelector("#ffForm").action = this.$data.merchantPaymentInfo.merchantUrl;

              }

              //
              alert(JSON.stringify(returnData));
              (this.$refs['ffForm'] as any).submit();

},

(this.$refs['ffForm'] as any).submit();
```

Comment: The error message is explicit, the this.$el doen't exists.  
Can you put you full code of the insertion

Comment: @DavidAnsermot hi, I updated the full code the 'data' is the object that pass the value to database for getting the response.

Comment: not your issue ... but `.then(function (response) { return response; })` is redundant - get rid of it

Comment: Still don't see where you set `this.$el` ?

Comment: `this.$el` is undefined until the component is mounted. Also, it could be a text node or a comment node depending on the specifics of the component

Comment: @DavidAnsermot - it's a `vue` thing

Comment: What you can do is `console.log(this.$el)` and `console.log(this.$el?.nodeName)` - what is the result?

Comment: @JaromandaX thank for the reply, I have found my problem and solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the code I commented it's still working when I do console.log(this.$el) after I delete the code everything works well.

[this.$el](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ACsY.png)

[cause of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMVj2.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).